# alert("{{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}}") is showing me an empty alert box

Tags: javascript, laravel, pusher

I am trying to set up pusher with laravel. I following the steps here at this link: [pusher workshop](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/getting-started/pusher-js-debugging.html)
My env variables in .env file are like this:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID= 255785
PUSHER_APP_KEY= r7db42g80u25689132l2
PUSHER_APP_SECRET= f2gt87w4tw652s2d4q98
```

I have this javascript code:

```
<script>
    alert("{{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}}");
    var pusher = new Pusher("{{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}}");
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
    channel.bind('test-event', function(data) {
      alert(data.text);
    });
</script>
```

The alert in the begging is showing me an empty alert window. This means that {{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}} return an empty string. I run the below code to clear the configuration cache but the situation keeps the same.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Also I double checked the other configurations and all look fine.

Comment: `PUSHER_APP_ID= 255785` - Do you really have a space between the `=` and the value, or is that just a typo here on SO?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes I really have a space. I just tried to remove the space and run php artisan config:cache again ,and now it is alerting. Thank you , I did not know that the space in the .env had an effect like that :/

Comment: Can you try to put `env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')` in template html instead of javascript code to make sure you are able to receive this value in blade file.

Comment: You probably don't want to be caching your config while in development.  Try `php artisan config:clear`, and make sure `bootstrap/cache/config.php` is gone.

Comment: For clearing cache, command is `php artisan cache:clear`